# USB keyboard doesn't work on GRUB boot menu when connected through USB-C hub

Tags: ubuntu, boot, keyboard, grub

I have Win 11 / Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot on a Dell XPS 15 7590.

I have one of those USB-C hubs where I connect my monitor, webcam, and keyboard on. And that connects to the USB-C port on the laptop. It all works fine when either OS is loaded but the keyboard and monitor doesn't work on the GRUB boot menu.

When connected directly to a USB-A port on the laptop, it works as expected.

Can anyone shed some light on this and possibly have a fix to this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if you can use the keyboard, when plugged into the USB-C hub, to access the PC BIOS/UEFI setup menu... no need to make any changes; just see if key presses are shown. If that doesn't work, then likely the USB-C port cannot be used before an OS has booted, at least the BIOS version on that PC.

Check if the latest BIOS version is installed, if not, update [from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=02p03).

Answer (score 0):

In my case GRUB by default only respond to "Enter" key only.
HOwever if press right Ctrl 5-6 times - grub starts respond to every key.